# commitlog analysis in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I found the commitlog(.log) files in the folder, and would like to analyze them. For example, I wanna know which query is executed in the history of the machine. Is there any code to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Commit log files are specific for a version of Cassandra, and you may need to tinker with [CommitLogReader](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogReader.java), etc.   You can find more information in the documentation on [Change Data Capture](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html).

But the main issue for you is that commit log doesn't contain the query executed, it contains the data that is modified.  What you really need is the audit functionality - here you have several choices:

- It's built-in into upcoming Cassandra 4.0 - see the [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/audit_logging.html) on how to use it
- use [ecAudit](https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit) plugin open sourced by Ericsson - it supports Cassandra 2.2, 3.0 & 3.11
- if you use DataStax Enterprise (DSE) it has [built-in support for audit logging](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.0/security/secAuditTOC.html)

Comment: We use the ecAudit plugin on some of our deploys, and have had good success with it.